# delln5010 caddy dualboot does not recognise (SOS)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, multi-boot, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to use my old delln5010 laptop as dualboot OS with hdd caddy and SSD installed.
In main internal drive (SSD) i have Windows 10 and in HDD caddy i have UBUNTU with GRAB.

When starting execution, i have directly windows 10 bootloader starting with no sign of grab, though in BIOS i have selected to boot CD/DVD+RW as a first choice.

Question:

> > Can i use this combination?
> >     do i need to replace grab into WINDOWS 10 drive(SSD)? Does it help?

Could you suggest any solution for that problem? i would appreciate!